# Why a try catch with removeItemAtIndexPath?

Tags: swift, try-catch, nsfilemanager

I'm curious as to why removeItemAtPath needs to be wrapped in a try/catch block in Swift 2

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(localPath.path!)
```

Can there be a scenario where a file cannot be removed from a local path, and when could this plausibly occur?

Comment: File is locked? File has wrong access privileges?

Comment: See also "Discussion" at the bottom of https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1408573-removeitematpath?language=objc

Comment: Thanks both. There is little possibility that the file in question cannot be removed, but I'll cater for that eventuality just in case.

Comment: No one has mention that it can fail if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. I already test for it's existence first.

Comment: But the call to `removeItemAtPath` doesn't know that.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, you're right about that.